# Django - Incorporating new models with their own pages

Tags: python, html, django

I have managed to set up one model within my Django project and can create posts within it and display those posts through views and templates, however, I don't appear to be able to do the same with the new Models I've created. I have attempted to do this as I have done with the initial Model, which is to set up its own html files, just as the first one, as well as similar entries in urls.py in the main project folder and views.py in the app folder.

**Edit for more context:** Basically, the Article model has been set up with the templates article_detail.html and article_list.html and all of the entries within that model are pulled from the Admin app and are viewable. I have created another model, Offensive, and would also like to do the same as with the Article entries, so I attempted to copy what I had done and made the Offensive model it's own templates (offensive_detail.html and offensive_list.html:).
This does not appear to have worked, however. Creating a link for Offensive on  base_template.html does not go anywhere, it just stays on the same page. Does not re-direct to the offensive details page that will show the list of offensive articles.

My intent is to have different categories aligned with different models and have all of those categories and corresponding pages as links within a navbar.

I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong, or even if I'm anywhere near right.
Help would be very much appreciated.

[Here is the folder structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmzqs.png)

Files under the app folder:

article_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="article-detail">
    <div class="article">
        <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
        <p>{{ article.date }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

article_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Articles List</h1>
    <div class="articles">
        {% for article in articles %}
           <div class="article">
            <h2><a href="{% url 'articles:detail' slug=article.slug %}">{{ article.title }}</a></h2>
            <p>{{ article.date }}</p>
           </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

offensive_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="offensive_articles">
    <div class="offensive_list">
        <h2>{{ offensive_article.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ offensive_article.body }}</p>
        <p>{{ offensive_article.date }}</p>
    </div>
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

offensive_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Offensive Articles List</h1>
    <div class="offensive_articles">
        {% for offensive_article in offensive_articles %}
           <div class="offensive_article">
            <h2><a href="{% url 'articles:offensive_article' slug=article.slug %}">{{ offensive_article.title }}</a></h2>
            <p>{{ offensive_article.date }}</p>
           </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField() # URL of post
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # auto populate with the current time
    thumb = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', blank=True)
    # add in author

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Offensive(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField() # URL of post
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # auto populate with the current time
    thumb = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name = 'articles'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.article_list, name="list"),
    url(r'^$', views.offensive_list, name="offensive_list"),
    url(r"^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", views.article_detail, name="detail"),
    url(r"^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", views.offensive_detail, name="offensive_detail"),

]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article, Offensive, Defensive, Fitness, Coding


def article_list(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'articles/article_list.html', {'articles': articles})

def about(request):
    #return HttpResponse('about')
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def article_detail(request, slug):
    #return HttpResponse(slug)
    article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'articles/article_detail.html', { 'article':article })

def offensive_list(request):
    offensive_articles = Offensive.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'articles/offensive_list.html', { 'offensive_article': offensive_article })

def offensive_detail(request, slug):
    #return HttpResponse(slug)
    offensive_article = Offensive.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'articles/offensive_detail.html', { 'offensive_article': offensive_article })
```

From main folder "website":

ursl.py:

```
"""website URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from articles import urls
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from articles import views as article_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about),
    url(r'^$', article_views.article_list, name="home"),
    url(r'^offensive/', include('articles.urls')),
    url(r'^$', article_views.offensive_list, name="offensive"),


]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

base_template.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Orbitron:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- this will apear everywhere -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Articles</title>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            
            <!-- Logo -->
             <div class="navbar-header">
                

                <!-- <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button> -->


                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-family: 'Orbitron',sans-serif; color:red;">Neophyte</a>
             </div>

             <!-- Item -->
             <div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="{% url 'offensive' %}" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-family: 'Orbitron',sans-serif; color:white">&nbsp; Offensive
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    

             </div>


        </div>
    </nav>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<!-- <img src="{% static 'Neophyte_logo.jpg' %}"/> -->
<!-- href="{% url 'offensive' %}" -->
```

Comment: I'm not clear from your post what the actual problem is. Please describe either what errors you are getting, or what is not working as you expect.

Comment: Apologies, it was late and my brain was fried. Included and edit for more context above.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still unclear as to the problem. I think the relevant sentence is "Creating a link for Offensive on base_template.html does not go anywhere." - but you don't seem to share the base_template and I also don't know what "does not go anywhere" means. If you mean the link appears to do nothing when clicked, have you tried inspecting the actual HTML?

Comment: Update again to include base_template.html and a further clarification:
"Creating a link for Offensive on  base_template.html does not go anywhere, it just stays on the same page. Does not re-direct to the offensive details page that will show the list of offensive articles."

Basically how do I create links within a navbar for each model I have within my application to show the entries I have created within those models?

Answer (score 0):

Your urls seem a bit out of sync. You've got articles.urls included twice and two matching patterns for 'r'^$'.

What you have:

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls')),
url(r'^about/$', views.about),
url(r'^$', article_views.article_list, name="home"),
url(r'^offensive/', include('articles.urls')),
url(r'^$', article_views.offensive_list, name="offensive"),
```

What I think you might want:

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls')),
url(r'^offensive/', include('offensive.urls')),
url(r'^about/$', views.about),

# pick one of the following that you want for the root url
# currently will match the first one.
url(r'^$', article_views.article_list, name="home"),
url(r'^$', article_views.offensive_list, name="offensive"),
```

Or if it is just models separating, put it all in one?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^articles/', views.article_list, name="article_list"),
    url(r"^articles/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", views.article_detail, name="article_detail"),
    url(r'^offensive/', views.offensive_list, name="offensive_list"),
    url(r"^offensive/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", views.offensive_detail, name="offensive_detail"),

    url(r'^about/$', views.about),
    url(r'^$', views.about, name="home"),
]
```

Also, you probably want to be using the newer Path, instead of the url (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried what you said but i get error saying it cant find the "offensive" module.
If I'm going to include something like this:
```
url(r'^offensive/', include('offensive.urls')),
```
Do I need to make a seperate app for this?

Comment: if you want a separate set of urls for offensive then you may want an app, but you don't need it. You can put them all in articles.urls if you wish but your url will have articles as a prefix. Try the all in one solution to get things working, then break things out if you get too many (your own pref) going.

Comment: So I wouldnt mind articles as a prefix, but I'm really not sure how I go about doing that other than what I've already done. And does that mean I don't need offensive_detail.html and offensive_list.html, I just use the article list/detail .html files?
Apologies for the further questions. I'm just really having a hard time getting my head around how I do this.

Comment: Edit your question to list out the urls you want and what view each one should do, then we can show you a url pattern to accomplish.